# Cannot change button text

Tags: wordpress, button, wordpress-theming

The site is build with wordpress and using the favetheme,houzes theme for real estate theme site, and what seems to be the problem here i cannot change this button text `[Load more]` so what i need is to know where can i edit the button text.
Thank you

i've tried elementor but its not showing the button i think its attached to the section which is for showing featured properites, i tried with `edit page` and  the customize but i still couldn't change the text or the button it's self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it on back-end accessing cpanel, it was at shortcodes of houzes theme you can find, at property-cards-v5.php (you can check its name in elementor by trying to edit it) changed its content of `Load More`, it was attached to the section it was part of the slide show